# Javascript regex to match empty strings, non-digit characters or numbers with more than 1 digit?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match empty strings, non-digit characters or numbers with more than 1 digit.

Examples:

```
"", "a", "abc", "10"
```

I tried:

```
/^([^1-9]*)|(\d{2,})$/
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: [It works for me](http://regexr.com?2vr8j)!?

Comment: @JosephSilber For some reason it also matches single digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex for that:

```
/^(\d{2,}|[^\d]+|)$/
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have some doubts though:
/^(\d{2,}|[^\d]+|)$/ works,

/^([^\d]*)|(\d{2,})$/ doesn't work,

but

/^(([^\d]*)|(\d{2,}))$/ works? Why?

Comment: You do need to group all or conditions in a bracket that's why `/^[^\d]*|\d{2,}$/` didn't work for you but `/^([^\d]*|\d{2,})$/` did.

Comment: But how can this be called? If I do example.match(regex) it breaks because example is empty.

Comment: @mrfox This is built for allowing empty strings also. May I know what is the value of the your example string?

Comment: @anubhava the value of my example is an input field from the user, if the field is left empty it will be null. But this has been solved: check for null beforehand and set example to "".